# Terraform AWS Glue Table Error (Resource present, now absent)

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, aws-lake-formation

I'm working on a terraform module to deploy our various AWS data lake services. I'm encountering an error occasionally (not always) when deploying a table that we have setup as a governed table in LakeFormation.

The error code comes from the AWS provider and to the tune of "Resource was present, now absent". When trying to run apply again I receive an error because the resource actually exists in AWS from the initial run, but Terraform is confused thinking it wasn't created. I've tried adding depends_on blocks to upstream resources, but that hasn't had the desired effect so far.

Are there any workarounds or solutions folks have encountered to an issue like this?

```
resource "aws_glue_catalog_table" "governed_table" {

name = "orders"
database_name = "sales"

table_type = "GOVERNED"

partition_keys {
    name = "country"
    type = "string"
}

storage_descriptor {
    input_format = "org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.MapredParquetInputFormat"
    output_format = "org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.MapredParquetOutputFormat"
    location = "s3://${var.s3_bucket}/bronze/sales/orders/"
    ser_de_info {
        name = "sales_orders"
        parameters = {
            "serialization.format" = "1"
        }
        serialization_library = "org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.serde.ParquetHiveSerDe"
    }
    columns {
        name = "sale_id"
        type = "string"
        comment = ""
    }
    columns {
        name = "sale_amount"
        type = "float"
        comment = ""
    }
    columns {
        name = "sale_date"
        type = "int"
        comment = ""
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Please add any relevant code to the question.

Comment: What you've described sounds like a bug in the `hashicorp/aws` provider rather than a bug in your Terraform module: the error text you mentioned is returned by Terraform Core when it detects that a provider didn't implement the provider protocol correctly. This particular problem is often caused by the provider not properly handing "eventual consistency" in a remote API, so when it reads back the object it has just created the remote API returns "Not Found" instead of the actual object. If that's true then it will probably be challenging to work around and you should instead open a bug report.

Comment: You can send bug reports to the AWS provider team by creating an issue in [the provider's GitHub repository](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws).